# add element to array with string key in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I had already functioning code.
Some part of the code should change two values of queryParams array:

```
myParam1 = 'sort_by';
myParam2 = 'sort_order';
queryParams[myParam1] = 'title';
if (queryParams[myParam2] == 'ASC') {
    queryParams[myParam2] = 'DESC';
} else { //DESC or undefined
    queryParams[myParam2] = 'ASC';
}
queryPairs = [];
for (var index in queryParams) {
    queryPairs.push(index + "=" + queryParams[index]);
}
```

Unfourtunately some logic has changed and now sometimes `queryParams` has length 0 at the beginning of this script and then this part failes.

```
queryParams[myParam1] = 'title';
```

and

```
queryParams[myParam2] = 'DESC'
```

lines do not change queryParams.length,so the length is still 0 and the loop

```
for (var index in queryParams){
```

do not work as expected.

I have not found how to add key/value into the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're being a bit confused by the fact that JavaScript's standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).

You're not using `queryParams` as an array in the code you've quoted. You're using it as an *object*. Objects don't have a `length` property by default.

You haven't said what changed, so it's difficult to help you, but note that even if `queryParams` is an array and you add a property to it as you are, the `length` will remain `0`. The `length` of an array only relates to a special class of properties (ones that meet the definition of an "array index"), not to all properties.

Some examples that may help:

```
var a = []; // a is an array
console.log(a.length); // "0"
a['foo'] = 'bar';
console.log(a.length); // "0", the `foo` property doesn't have any effect on `length`
a[0] = 'zero';
console.log(a.length); // "1", the `0` property *does* have an effect on `length`

var o = {}; // o is an object
var myParam1 = 'sort_by';
var myParam2 = 'sort_order';
var propertyName;

o[myParam1] = 'foo';
o[myParam2] = 'DESC';

for (propertyName in o) {
    console.log(propertyName); // "sort_by" and then "sort_order" (the order is not defined)
}
```

Comment: Before changes queryParams[myParam1] and queryParams[myParam2] always were defined, so the code just changed values of those two items. But after changes, there are situations when queryParams[myParam1] and queryParams[myParam2] are undefined and in this case just writing queryParams[myParam2] = 'DESC' failes, because it doesn't appear in for loop. I need it to appearin for loop, what should I do?

Comment: @renathy: That assignment shouldn't fail, not if `queryParams` is an object (plain object or array, either way). It may be that `queryParams` isn't initialized at all, in which case you can do this: `if (!queryParams) { queryParams = {}; }` before assigning to its properties. Another way you'll see that written is `queryParams = queryParams || {};`